# ¿Como ordenar un a matriz segun las columnas sistema de recomendación en python?

Tags: python, algoritmos, matemáticas

Quiero hacer un sistema de recomendación basada en el usuario siguiendo [el artículo del blog de Salem Marafi.](http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/) con una matriz de similitud.

La base de datos esta [un fichero csv disponible aqui](http://www.salemmarafi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lastfm-matrix-germany.csv). Esta un base de datos de lo que han escuchado los auditores de last.fm una radio alemana.

Aqui esta como hice el autor.

- Crea una matriz de similitud.
- Verifica cual estan los artículos/cansion/articulos (depende de la base de datos) el usario  ha consumido.
- Para cada artículos/cansion/articulos y consegui la parte superior.
- Consegui el registro del consumo
- Calcula un puntaje de similitud con una formula.
- Recomenda con el puntaje más alto

Sin embargo el codigo esta en Python obsoleto.

La parte que no estoy capaz actualizar esta cuando hace el autor una bucle sobre las líneas y las columnas que llena con puntajes de semejenzas. Marcamos con 0 artículos que el utilisaro que ya ha consumido/escuchado porque no es necesario aconsejralo de nuevo. Pueden ayurdarme puestar el código en código actualizado?

Aqui esta **el codigo que intento hacer para actualizar el codigo** que ha hecho Salem Marafi el autor :

```
#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

        if data.iloc[i][j] == 1:
            data_sims.iloc[i][j] = 0
        else:
        product_top_names = data_neighbours
        product_top_sims = data_ibs.iloc[product].sort_values(ascending=False)
        user_purchases = data_germany.iloc[user,product_top_names]

            data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)
```

Aqui esta el **mensaje de error** :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-7addb4d1dfef> in <module>()
      9         else:
     10             product_top_names = data_neighbours
---> 11             product_top_sims = data_ibs.iloc[product].sort_values(ascending=False)
     12             user_purchases = data_germany.iloc[user,product_top_names]
     13 

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1326         else:
   1327             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1328             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
   1329 
   1330     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1740         # a single integer
   1741         else:
-> 1742             key = self._convert_scalar_indexer(key, axis)
   1743 
   1744             if not is_integer(key):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _convert_scalar_indexer(self, key, axis)
    234         ax = self.obj._get_axis(min(axis, self.ndim - 1))
    235         # a scalar
--> 236         return ax._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=self.name)
    237 
    238     def _convert_slice_indexer(self, key, axis):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in _convert_scalar_indexer(self, key, kind)
   1256 
   1257         if kind == 'iloc':
-> 1258             return self._validate_indexer('positional', key, kind)
   1259 
   1260         if len(self) and not isinstance(self, ABCMultiIndex,):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in _validate_indexer(self, form, key, kind)
   3337             pass
   3338         elif kind in ['iloc', 'getitem']:
-> 3339             self._invalid_indexer(form, key)
   3340         return key
   3341 

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in _invalid_indexer(self, form, key)
   1467                         "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(
   1468                             form=form, klass=type(self), key=key,
-> 1469                             kind=type(key)))
   1470 
   1471     def get_duplicates(self):

TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [a perfect circle] of <type 'str'>
```

El problema esta cuando intentamos ordenar la matriz de similitud `data_ibs`:

```
data_ibs.iloc[product].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

**¿Como puedo devolver una matriz ordenada sobre cada canción ?**

Aqui esta un visatzo de la matriz :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta **lo que el ha echo, solo la parte que nos interesa** :

```
#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

        if data.ix[i][j] == 1:
            data_sims.ix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            product_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[product][1:10]
            product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]
            user_purchases = data_germany.ix[user,product_top_names]

            data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)
```

---

Aqui esta **el código completo del autor** :

```
# --- Import Libraries --- #

import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

# --- Read Data --- #
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# --- Start Item Based Recommendations --- #
# Drop any column named "user"
data_germany = data.drop('user', 1)

# Create a placeholder dataframe listing item vs. item
data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=data_germany.columns,columns=data_germany.columns)

# Lets fill in those empty spaces with cosine similarities
# Loop through the columns
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
    # Loop through the columns for each column
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
      # Fill in placeholder with cosine similarities
      data_ibs.ix[i,j] = 1-cosine(data_germany.ix[:,i],data_germany.ix[:,j])

# Create a placeholder items for closes neighbours to an item
data_neighbours = pd.DataFrame(index=data_ibs.columns,columns=[range(1,11)])

# Loop through our similarity dataframe and fill in neighbouring item names
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)):
    data_neighbours.ix[i,:10] = data_ibs.ix[0:,i].order(ascending=False)[:10].index

# --- End Item Based Recommendations --- #

# --- Start User Based Recommendations --- #

# Helper function to get similarity scores
def getScore(history, similarities):
   return sum(history*similarities)/sum(similarities)

# Create a place holder matrix for similarities, and fill in the user name column
data_sims = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index,columns=data.columns)
data_sims.ix[:,:1] = data.ix[:,:1]

#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

        if data.ix[i][j] == 1:
            data_sims.ix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            product_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[product][1:10]
            product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]
            user_purchases = data_germany.ix[user,product_top_names]

            data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)

# Get the top songs
data_recommend = pd.DataFrame(index=data_sims.index, columns=['user','1','2','3','4','5','6'])
data_recommend.ix[0:,0] = data_sims.ix[:,0]

# Instead of top song scores, we want to see names
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    data_recommend.ix[i,1:] = data_sims.ix[i,:].order(ascending=False).ix[1:7,].index.transpose()

# Print a sample
print data_recommend.ix[:10,:4]
```

Comment: "Pueden ayuradme puestarla en código actualizado?" - no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: No entiendo el título ni la pregunta

Comment: @lois6b El código no está actualizado y he intentado hacerlo pero fallido.

Comment: Cuando vi el título de la pregunta pensé que me encontraba en el Meta, pero no... está en SO.

Comment: @A.Cedano fue un olvido :/ ;)

Comment: Ningún problema, aunque el actual título no es _del todo_ castellano. Creo que debería ser: _¿Cómo poner al día un sistema de recomendación escrito en Python antiguo?_ o aún más elaborada. Saludos.

Comment: @Marine1 el error que te esta dando actualmente es porque estás tratando de utilizar una cadena como índice, no creo que tenga mucho que ver con la versión de Python que estés utilizando

Comment: @yorodm Pienso que tienes razon. En verdad quiero obtener por cada canción  las 10 más similares canciones, es por decir ordenar cada lineas segun las columnas. Lo que intentado hacer el autor : `product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]`

Comment: @Marine1 que tan complicado te seria hacer una funcion resumen que diera un numero unico a cada autor??? creo que eso te resuelve el problema

Comment: @yorodm Pero la recomendación no sería personalizado por cada utilisador...

Comment: Marine1 como dice @yorodm el error se debe a usar `iloc`, que trabaja con índices solamente, pero le pasas el nombre de la columna. Debes usar `ix` o `loc`.

Comment: @FJSevilla, si tienes razón